# Changing Application Icon in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, icons, wxwidgets

I have a Application project in VS 2022 and I added the appropriate .ico file to the icon resources, it is listed as IDI_ICON1. In all the research I have done, it indicates to open the Project Properties and then go to the Applications section and change the icon. I do not have an applications section.[image: Properties Window]
There were other methods that indicated using the icon properties of the individual file, but that property doesn't exist? I am sure I am missing something simple.

I added the icon file to the resource file and tried to set the icon but cannot find how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Desktop Application, you could have just replaced the file **small.ico** with your new icon file, this file can be found in your projects folder, using this method there would be no other changes required.

Alternatively if you've already added a new icon to the resource file and you want to change the icon that way, then search your code for `LoadIcon`

You should see a line similar to:

`wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));`

`IDI_SMALL` will be the default small icon ID, which points to `small.ico`, you can replace `IDI_SMALL` with your icon ID `IDI_ICON1`

Presuming your icon is in the correct format then that is all that is required.

This will change the small icon used in the applications title bar.

Comment: I looked in the projects folder and didn't see the small.ico file and didn't get any results when searching for LoadIcon, IDI_SMALL, or wcex...

I just noticed that there are two different types of icons... The icon for the application itself and the icon in the title bar of the running application.
I didn't mention that I am using wxWidgets and that is the icon that is showing for the application and it looks like the Application title is using the default windows logo?

Comment: OK if using wxWidgets try looking for `SetIcon`

Comment: I only found one instance of SETICON and it was a define in resource.h

Answer (score 0):

@Rick,

Please post how you added the icon to the resource file. And what resource file did you add it to?

Also explain more how did you create a project in MSVC. There multiple ways to do so.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please, move it all to comments to the question.

Comment: I added the icon by right clicking the images.rc* folder, selected the Add Resource, selected the icon option and then imported. It shows up as an item in the icon list of the resources.
I am pretty sure I created it by using Windows Desktop Application

Comment: @Rick, look at the minimal sample provided with wxWidgets- it gives you an rc file which you can update and use the either updated icon or a new icon id.